# What's the mechanism used to extract my user name on a website?

Tags: data-leakage, websites

I was browsing this forum

http://openelec.tv/forum/64-installation/40869-putting-openelec-onto-sd-card-using-usb-reader-from-a-mac-for-raspberry-pi

,and realised that they show my hostname and my (computer's login-)user-name. How does my computer communicate these things to the website?

**NOTE:** Mystery solved. The person in that forum thread just happened to have the same host- and username as I did. I checked on another computer.

Sorry, I should have checked first. Moderators: Perhaps please delete the question.

Comment: I'd suspect cookies

Comment: Where is it showing username? Can you include a screenshot (blacked out if you don't want to reveal your actual username)?

Comment: I meant the terminal output in 2nd post: "Lukass-MacBook-Pro:Desktop lukas$ diskutil list" But sorry, I just found out what the problem is! The guy posting just happened to have the same login-name and same hostname as I! Aah, stupid. I checked on another computer and it worked fine. Thank your for reading though.

Answer (score 2):

Hostname can be retrieved by a DNS lookup on your IP address (PTR record). Your IP address is sent to the website at TCP level as your browser makes requests to retrieve content. The website simply uses that information.

Regarding username.... you do not specify which username is displayed. I can only assume you have registered and logged into the site.

Comment: no, i mean my mac username. I have never been to that website before.

Comment: Mystery solved, see at the top. Thank you for answering though!